# Is it possible to paste value into editable string of terminal in key binding function?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I knew about binding in bash.
`bind -x '"\C-k":"mc"'` — this example is allow to run mc when editable command is not finished.
I think, that it way allow make a lot of macros-completions. It would be helpful when work without X11.

I tried paste a test value this ways:

```
bind -x '"\C-o":"echo -n 123"'
bind -x '"\C-o":"echo -n 123 >> /dev/pts/12"
bind -x '"\C-o":"xclip -out"'
bind -x '"\C-o":"expect exp.txt"'
```

But result is

[image]

Another ideas:

- To use clipboard of bash (Ctrl-w, Ctrl-y). Man bash calls it “kill ring”. But i can’t to find how use it programmatic method.
- To echo into a program that simulates pressing each letter of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. `man bash` speaks about it in description of `bind` command.

Editable string have variables: `READLINE_LINE`, `READLINE_MARK`, `READLINE_POINT`.

Then a command will be like this:

```
bind -x '"\C-o":"READLINE_LINE=$READLINE_LINE$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')"'
```

[image]